# StackOverflowError en Eclipse Oxygen usando Swing

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo este error cuando ejecuto la interfaz

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>     at java.awt.Window.init(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Window.(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.Frame.(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Frame.(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JFrame.(Unknown Source)
>       at sisley.main.User_Create.(User_Create.java:55)
>       at sisley.main.User_Create.(User_Create.java:19) Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

Este es mi codigo que es solo una clase que complementa a la interfaz main

```
package sisley.main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class User_Create extends JFrame {   
    private User_Create z1 = new User_Create();
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField_3;
    private JTextField textField_4;
    private JTextField textField_5;
    private JTextField textField_6;
    private JTextField textField_7;
    private JTextField textField_8;

    int idMixure = 0;
    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<Parlamentarios> p1 = new ArrayList<Parlamentarios>();
    ArrayList<Asesores> A1 = new ArrayList<Asesores>();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    User_Create frame = new User_Create();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public User_Create() {
        setTitle("Creacion de Usuario");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 527, 477);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        Parlamentarios pr1 = new Parlamentarios();
        Asesores as1 = new Asesores();  
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Crear");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 pr1.setUsuario(textField.getText());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pr1.getIdPar());
                 p1.add(idMixure, pr1);                  

            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(43, 353, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Cancelar");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                z1.hide();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(362, 353, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(200, 42, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(134, 93, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setBounds(134, 149, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_2);
        textField_2.setColumns(10);

        textField_3 = new JTextField();
        textField_3.setBounds(134, 203, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_3);
        textField_3.setColumns(10);

        textField_4 = new JTextField();
        textField_4.setBounds(137, 264, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_4);
        textField_4.setColumns(10);

        textField_5 = new JTextField();
        textField_5.setBounds(275, 93, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_5);
        textField_5.setColumns(10);

        textField_6 = new JTextField();
        textField_6.setBounds(275, 149, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_6);
        textField_6.setColumns(10);

        textField_7 = new JTextField();
        textField_7.setBounds(275, 203, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_7);
        textField_7.setColumns(10);

        textField_8 = new JTextField();
        textField_8.setBounds(275, 264, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_8);
        textField_8.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblParlamentario = new JLabel("Parlamentario");
        lblParlamentario.setBounds(104, 44, 86, 17);
        contentPane.add(lblParlamentario);

        JLabel lblParlamentario_1 = new JLabel("Asesor 1");
        lblParlamentario_1.setBounds(155, 124, 54, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblParlamentario_1);

        JLabel lblAsesor = new JLabel("Asesor 3");
        lblAsesor.setBounds(155, 178, 54, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblAsesor);

        JLabel lblAsesor_3 = new JLabel("Asesor 5");
        lblAsesor_3.setBounds(155, 239, 54, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblAsesor_3);

        JLabel lblAsesor_1 = new JLabel("Asesor 2");
        lblAsesor_1.setBounds(295, 124, 54, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblAsesor_1);

        JLabel lblAsesor_2 = new JLabel("Asesor 4");
        lblAsesor_2.setBounds(295, 180, 54, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblAsesor_2);

        JLabel lblAsesor_4 = new JLabel("Asesor 6");
        lblAsesor_4.setBounds(295, 239, 54, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblAsesor_4);

        JLabel lblAsesor_5 = new JLabel("Asesor 7");
        lblAsesor_5.setBounds(155, 295, 65, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblAsesor_5);

        JLabel lblAsesort = new JLabel("Asesort 8");
        lblAsesort.setBounds(295, 295, 66, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblAsesort);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Evitar éste `StackOverflowError`:

- Se puede optar por eliminar la linea `private User_Create z1 = new User_Create();`, puesto que ya tienes una instancia que llamaste `frame` dentro del hilo de ejecución en `main`, de ese modo evitas la recursion infinita que produce el desbordamiento. *(o bien si deseas usar ´z1´ tienes que descartar la instancia `frame`)*
- Por otro lado y sin ser causa del error, el método `hide()`. Está en desuso desde la `JDK 1.5`, reemplazado por `setVisible()`, lógicamente deberas quitar aquel `z1.hide()` ya sea por `System.exit()` `setVisible(false)` o por el método `dispose()`, esto dependiendo de tus requerimientos entre uno u otro porque se comportan de una manera distinta.

Comment: Mira, si elimino frame y solo uso z1, no me funcionan ni setVisible(false) ni dispose()

Comment: Acabo de hacer una prueba con z1 y todo ok, veo el formulario y al cancelar la ventana se va con System.exit(), setVisible(false) y dispose().

Comment: Si, pero al momento de usarlo como un Jframe que sale de un Jframe main no me deja al momento de ingresar datos, despues intendo salir y no me deja

Comment: Si quieres puedes ver mi codigo completo y ver que esta pasando https://github.com/ChutLuis/SisLeyMkIV

Comment: OK Luis, el problema es que tienes multiples instancias de ventanas y ademas redundantes, ya sabemos que en un sitio como este no hacemos tareas, pero solo te dare una pauta inicial...  borra o comenta el método main de User_Create, borra z1, haz que extienda de JDialog no de JFrame y cambia el modo de cierre a DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE, por ultimo coloca dispose() en el listener de Cancelar. Con lo anterior puedes seguir modificando los errores similares de las demás ventanas.

Comment: Disculpa la verdad no entendi que quieres que haga, ya borre z1 y lo extendi de JDialog pero despues no entiendo que hacer

Comment: Ya me salio, perdon por las molestias te lo agradezco mucho